# How to parse a file for multiple strings?

Tags: shell, text-processing, string, html

I have a large number of HTML files some of which contain a section starting "`<div>` specific text" and ending with `</div>`. I'd like to use a bash script to remove these sections.

There are many other `div` sections, some of which overlap with the one I'm interested in.

I'd like to go through each file, outputting to a new file until reaching the start of the specific section; continue, incrementing and decrementing a counter with each `<div>` or `</div>` until the counter reaches zero, then resume outputting the file.

What are the most suitable approaches to use for this purpose? Speed isn't a priority.

Or is there a better way?

Sample input html:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Re: Something</title>
<link rel="important stylesheet" href="">
<style>div.headerdisplayname {font-weight:bold;}</style></head>
<body>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part1"><tr><td><div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">Subject: </div>Re: Something</td></tr><tr><td><div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">From: </div>sender@isp.com></td></tr><tr><td><div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">Date: </div>06/12/16 15:18</td></tr></table><table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part2"><tr><td><div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">To: </div>Sender 2 <sender2@isp.com></td></tr></table><br>
<div class="moz-text-html"  lang="x-unicode"><div dir="ltr">Dear Sender 2<div><br></div><div>A message</div><div><br></div><div>Mesage 1</div><div><ul><li>Message 2<br></li><li>Message 3<br></li><li>Message 4</li><li>Message 5<br></li><li>Message 6<br></li><li>Message 7<br></li><li>Message 8<br></li><li>Message 9<br></li></ul></div><div>Message 10</div><div><br></div><div>Message 11</div><div><br></div><div>Message 12</div><div><br></div><div>Message 13</div><div><br></div><div>Sender</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div></div><div class="gmail_extra"><br><div class="gmail_quote">On 5 December 2016 at 19:20, Sender 2 <span dir="ltr">&lt;<a href="mailto:sender2@isp.com" target="_blank">sender2@isp.com</a>&gt;</span> wrote:<br><blockquote class="gmail_quote" style="margin:0 0 0 .8ex;border-left:1px #ccc solid;padding-left:1ex"><font color="black" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<div style="font-family:arial,helvetica;font-size:10pt;color:black">
<div>
<font color="black" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Dear Sender 1,
<div><br>
</div>
<div>Reply 1</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div>Reply 2</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div>Sender 2</div><span class="HOEnZb"><font color="#888888">
<div><br>
</div>
<div>Sender 2</div>
<div>+telephone</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
<div><br>
</div>
</font></span></font>
</div>
</div>
</font></blockquote></div><br></div>
</div></body>
</html>
</table></div>
```

Removing the

> `<div` class="gmail_quote">

section gives output:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Re: Something</title>
<link rel="important stylesheet" href="">
<style>div.headerdisplayname {font-weight:bold;}</style></head>
<body>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part1"><tr><td><div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">Subject: </div>Re: Something</td></tr><tr><td><div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">From: </div>sender@isp.com></td></tr><tr><td><div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">Date: </div>06/12/16 15:18</td></tr></table><table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part2"><tr><td><div class="headerdisplayname" style="display:inline;">To: </div>Sender 2 <sender2@isp.com></td></tr></table><br>
<div class="moz-text-html"  lang="x-unicode"><div dir="ltr">Dear Sender 2<div><br></div><div>A message</div><div><br></div><div>Mesage 1</div><div><ul><li>Message 2<br></li><li>Message 3<br></li><li>Message 4</li><li>Message 5<br></li><li>Message 6<br></li><li>Message 7<br></li><li>Message 8<br></li><li>Message 9<br></li></ul></div><div>Message 10</div><div><br></div><div>Message 11</div><div><br></div><div>Message 12</div><div><br></div><div>Message 13</div><div><br></div><div>Sender</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div></div><div class="gmail_extra"><br>
</div></body>
</html>
</table></div>
```

Note that there may be multiple nested sections to remove.

Comment: Is "use a proper parser" an option, or not? If so, this is probably a [so] question.

Comment: To just remove the text is easy enough with something like: `cat test.html | sed 's#<div>remove this</div>##g'`.

Comment: 1) We can't help unless you show us an example of your input and the output you would want to see from it. 2) You will need to use a dedicated HTML parser and write a script.

Comment: Tigger's suggestion won't work because of repeated nested sections, all of which end in <\div>. I need to find the matching end.

Comment: do they have to be in the same line these strings? Maybe an example of output would useful in order to understand the problem.

Comment: @terdon I've posted the before and after code, by manually   following my proposed code - hope that helps clarify.

Comment: @fusion.slope Assume the strings can be anywhere in the file.

Comment: How about some specific responses?

I tried Pup [link](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup):
>cat input.html | pup ':not(div.gmail_quote)' > output.html
but that returned the entire html unchanged
whereas:
>cat input.html | pup 'div.gmail_quote' > output.html

Comment: How about some specific responses?

I tried Pup [link](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup):
    cat input.html | pup ':not(div.gmail_quote)' > output.html
but that returned the entire html unchanged
whereas:
    cat input.html | pup 'div.gmail_quote' > output.html
returned the unwanted section

Perhaps someone could suggest a suitable tool?

Comment: It's a pity this isn't well formed XML. Would have been really easy to do with e.g. XMLStarlet otherwise.